# Strip the string from the given file

Tags: python, pandas, string, strip

I want to strip a particular name from the below file.

```
from string import digits
ini_string = "53943_Sreerag_cde_one_check.xlsx"
print("initial string : ", ini_string)
remove_digits = str.maketrans('', '', digits)
res = ini_string.translate(remove_digits)
print("final string : ", res)
final=res[res.index(""):]
 print(final)
```

Here the output should be "Sreerag".

Comment: Are your file names of form: `<numbers>_<name>_cde_one_check.xlsx`?

Comment: @sotmot:Absolutly right.

Comment: That makes it so much simpler. Check out my answer.

Comment: A small change in code needed : Input "53943_Sreerag_cde_one_check.xlsx" or Sreerag_cde_one_check.xlsx  and output should be "Sreerag"

Answer (score 3):

Cool. So, there is a easier way to solve this - Use `split` function :)

```py
import pandas as pd

ini_string = ["53943_Sreerag_cde_one_check.xlsx", "Sreerag_cde_one_check.xlsx"]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["ini_string"] = ini_string

df["Name"] = df["ini_string"].str.split("_").str[-4]
print(df)

"""
Output:
                         ini_string     Name
0  53943_Sreerag_cde_one_check.xlsx  Sreerag
1        Sreerag_cde_one_check.xlsx  Sreerag
"""
```

Steps:

1. Split based on underscores
2. Take the 4th split value from the end. It is the name.

Comment: is it possible for a read a file name and split ?

Comment: By read a file name do you mean from a folder or a file with list of files as text? In that case, yes. The `split` operation can be performed on all variables that are strings.

Comment: A small change in code needed : Input "53943_Sreerag_cde_one_check.xlsx" or Sreerag_cde_one_check.xlsx and output should be "Sreerag"

Comment: @Sreerag, I have made changes which allow for this variation.

Comment: :Worked as expected. Thank you.

Comment: :Is it possible to extract a file name from .csv file and do the above steps.

Comment: Yes. It can be done.

Comment: :using pandas and dataframe is it possible

Comment: :ini_string = pd.read_csv(path)
    final = ini_string.split("_")
    try:
        # Check if the first value is int.
        int(final[0])
        Name=final[1].upper()
        print(Name)
    except:
        Name=final[0].upper()
        print(Name)

Comment: Yes. It can be. I have edited my answer. I really suggest that you accept an answer that helps you.

Comment: is it possible for 2 different file extensions .csv and .xlsx

Answer (score 2):

You can use split operation
ini_string = ini_string.split('-')[1]

Comment: @Sreerag, what exactly do you mean by reading a file name?

Comment: A small change in code needed : Input "53943_Sreerag_cde_one_check.xlsx" or Sreerag_cde_one_check.xlsx and output should be "Sreerag"